# PHP passthru functions return nothing

Tags: php, windows

Im using PHP 5.5.12 on windows 8.1 and the wmic is installed on the server

i want to get the bios serial number i wrote

```
<?php 

passthru('wmic bios get serialnumber 2>&1') ;
```

it returns the bios and everything is OK

i try the same line on a different PC which has also windows 8.1 and php 5.5.12 and wmic is installed

nothing returned at all !!

i tried different version of PHP 5.6 PHP 7 nothing returned also

i tried another php functions like exec,system still nothing returned

where is the problem exactly ?

Comment: If you run the following command in CMD, what does it say?

    php -r "passthru('wmic bios get serialnumber 2>&1');"